# "To put into a bottle" verb

Tags: verbs

I'm Brazilian and in the portuguese language we have a verb do describe the act of *putting something in a bottle*. The verb is [*"engarrafar"*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/engarrafar).

Is there an equivalent in english?

Comment: It says there only! *to bottle up!* However, it is an idiom as well meaning something different. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/To-stop-control-or-not-show-emotions

Comment: For a factory process, you can use the verb, "to bottle" as in "This factory bottles Coca Cola products." The phrase "to bottle up," has a connotation of putting contents under pressure, as in "Don't keep your emotions bottled up inside."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Bottle* serves equally as a verb with exactly that sense. Here are some instances from Google:

> We bottle our milk in clear glass, not cardboard cartons.
>   Tonight I bottled six quarts of mead.
>   We are bottling our 40th vintage of Napa Valley Cabernet Sauvignon for release later this year.

Comment: So, can I say that the word 'bottle' is both a noun and a verb?

Comment: @talles Yes, indeed.

Comment: Dunno about US, but in the UK, the slang verb ***to bottle [it]*** means to back down from a confrontation or other fraught situation (due to lack of *bottle = courage*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's interesting. Is *bottle* related to *Dutch courage*, or that only an Americanism?

Comment: You'd think *[dutch] courage = bottle [of beer]* (well, [I certainly did](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106004/losing-bottles-and-bottling-out#comment216087_106006) last year on ELU). But according to OED *bottle=courage* derives from some Victorian slang usage ***no bottle** - no good; bad(ly), useless(ly),* which I've never encountered. I suppose it's probably irrelevant to mention that in my early drinking days, the only beer ***I*** normally had in bottles (as opposed to cans, or draught beer) was the brand [Courage Light Ale](http://www.beersofeurope.co.uk/courage-light-ale)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I always understood Dutch courage to be gin, originally a Dutch import.

Comment: I think the Dutch originally *invented* gin (or perfected the recipe, I dunno). But ***London** [dry] gin* is an established subcategory (despite my unpatriotic preference for *Bombay Sapphire!* :) I doubt those entrepreneurial early Victorians would have allowed the Dutch to make significant profits at our expense before we got tooled up with our own distilleries. Whatever - I think there's no doubt *Dutch courage* has always meant "alcohol-fuelled" (by gin or whatever), but it's probably much affected by the fact that "Dutch" very often means "faulty, ersatz" in many of our idioms.